# Extract data from website using PHP

Tags: php

I want to extract data from the following website for example:

http://stationmeteo.meteorologic.net/metar/your-metar.php?icao=LFMN&day=010513

in the URL, I can change the &day, and the icao to retrieve the data I want.

The data are (in order) the following:

Time and date in UTC or local format#Temperature (° C)#Humidity (%)#.... 
(they are separated by the # symbol)

But the question is how to extract some of the data written in the website via PHP.

For example I wan't to extract the temperature at 00:30 01/05/2013.

from the line:

```
00:30 01/05/2013#17#72#9##0#330#1015######12#>10#NNW##19#
```

I can see that the temperature is 17.

Is there anyway to get this number via PHP?

Comment: You may want to clarify what step you're unsure of. Retrieving the content at a certain URL as a string? Parsing it to find the information you need? From a first look at your problem, I think I can at least answer your final question with "Yes."

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlow. Yes, there is a way. `file_get_contents`, then regex. Give it a try, and post a question (after you read the rules) if you can't handle the regular expression. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use file_get_contents(URL HERE); and then find your way through the data structure either with regular expressions or exploding. Good luck!